# Console.time always returns 0.000ms

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm using `node-webkit` to create a album manager and I'm setting up a recursive scan to find all my photos. I'm scanning some 10k files, but console.time just keeps returning 0.000ms. I know the scan is happening pretty quick, but it's not that quick. **Am I doing something wrong?**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'I:/pictures/';

console.time('read-directory');

var scanDirectory = function(path) {
    fs.readdir(path,function(err,files) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            files.forEach(function(file) {
                fs.stat(path + file, function(err,stats) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        if(stats.isDirectory()) {
                            scanDirectory(path + file + '/');
                        } else {
                            console.log(path + file);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}

scanDirectory(path);

console.timeEnd('read-directory');
```

Comment: fs.readdir is asynchronous. console.timeEnd is being called before it ever reads anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `fs.readdir` which is asynchronous. So your timer is not depending of your scanDirectory execution.

In fact, it's just launching your function when you call `scanDirectory(path)` then directly after stop the timer.

If you want you can use `fs.readdirSync` which will prevent to jump to the timer end as it's a synchronise function. The problems, is that will freeze your application (if your use it's directly like that) during this time and problably slow your execution.

In order to get the time of execution of your asynchrone function you can use the profiler tool of Node-webkit. But you will need to filter and sum them manually...

The other solution is to use `timely` (it's an npm package ) that can time synchronous or asynchronous functions.